# Implement a AlertBox in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, alert

For my project i use storyboard and arc and now i want to implement an AlertBox where i can register me with username and password.

First of all i check if i am already registered with a Query (already implemented). If i am already registered the AlertBox should not appear and my normal View should be shown.
If i am not registered the AlertBox should appear and i must register my device (connected to AD).

The part with the registration and connection to the AD, SQL-Server is already implemented.
I just want to know how i can "pop-up" such a Alert box with 2 Textfields and Labels in my storyboard.

If you know any example codes/tutorials i would be very happy :)

I hope you can help me with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more info here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

You simply create an UIAlertView and set it's style to UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput.

Then use the delegate's methods to get the value in the text fields.

Here is a little sample: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/